# Accessing values from fetched object?

Tags: django

models.py

```
class Period(CommonInfo):
    order_value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class LeaseDiscount(CommonInfo):
    amount  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    amountpayed = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    leaseterm = models.ForeignKey(LeaseTerm)
    period_date = models.ForeignKey(Period)
```

views.py

I want to list all the discounts I have for certain periods of my lease,query is as follows :

```
    period = Period.objects.filter(order_value__gte = start, order_value__lte = end).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            "leasediscount_set",
            queryset=LeaseDiscount.objects.filter(is_active=True, leaseterm =  activeterm),
            to_attr="all_discount"
        )
    )
```

but when I display the list of periods in my template for the all_discount the output is `[<LeaseDiscount: LeaseDiscount object>]`

Why? How I access the values of this object? In general am I doing it the right way?

UPDATE:
template

```
          {% for field1 in data.period%}


                    <td> {{ field1.all_discount }}</td>
```

Comment: You could add a `__str__` method to the `LeaseDiscount` model and return whatever you'd like to be displayed by default. Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#str

Comment: You should show your template. Generally though this is just showing you that you have a queryset; you would iterate through and access the individual items as normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by Daniel,You can iterate through the list given by objects.filter as :

In view:

```
    for data in period:  # period is a LeaseDiscount object
        print data.some_field_name   # LeaseDiscount model fields
```

Or in template:
     Firstly pass the object by render/render_to_response then use something like this:

```
 {% for data in period %}
   {{ data.some_field_name }}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks  should I actually create a field in Perio to hold this value? 

Since I am getting error
'Period' object has no attribute 'some_field_name'

Comment: I am using :) my own name. I posted it to be consistent with answer.
But it is still not clear for me this field should exist in model or not?

Comment: Please use the field names of LeaseDiscount model/table. I gave this name - 'some_field_name' for example.

Comment: it works for me  without creating additional field in actual model.This is was my question basically.

Comment: @BorisTheAnimal I am glad it helped you. :)

Comment: Nice name btw. @BorisTheAnimal